# C# .net Сессии страницы

Tags: c#, сессия

Есть проект, если в браузере открыть туже страничку в новой вкладке, я так понимаю сессия висит таже. Так вот чтоб не было параллельного обращения к одной и той же сессии как отслеживать ПОВТОРНОЕ открытие сессии и не давать ее открывать (ограничиться одной). Можно выдавать уведомительное сообщение.C#

Comment: Интересно откуда взялся подобный вопрос - что стало проблемой? Подобные проблемы:
1 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922502/limit-only-one-session-per-user-in-asp-net
2 - http://www.sharepoint4developers.net/en-nz/post/limit-session-account.aspx
3 - http://graciesdad.wordpress.com/2007/05/26/multiple-browser-windows-with-one-session-state/

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не связан с C#. Идентификатор сессии записывается в куку в браузере и передаётся браузером в заголовке с каждым запросом. Передачу куки не избежать, если только не придумать какой-нибудь костыль на javascript - например при деактивации вкладки удалять куку и хранить её в переменной, а при активации - писать значение в куку.